# How to assign a Url to a PSButtonCell action

Tags: plist, tweak, theos

Hi guys I have been working on this tweak an for the most part I'm done. The only thing that I have left in mind is to add a donate button to my preference bundle. I have already created a cell with a label and action, I just need to know how to assign a url to the action and where I need to put the assign code in. Do I put it in my tweak.xm? In a separate plist? Please help, and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your action in a separate file in your setting bundle. it'd better use preference_bundle template provided by theos.
About URL, you can have a look at this, https://github.com/hbang/NotiQuiet/blob/master/prefs/ADNQListController.m
I have test the method openURL, it still works although this file was written 8 months ago.

For details, http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Preferences_specifier_plist this is always helpful.